# Powershell 7 import-module does not persist across sessions

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

If I open a new **Powershell 7** session and run `get-command Get-Website`
the response I get is

```
Get-Command: The term 'Get-Website' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

If I then run `import-Module WebAdministration` and again run `get-command Get-Website`, this time I get the expectefd output of

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Get-Website                                        1.0        WebAdministration
```

If I close the Powershell 7 session, open a new one and run `get-command Get-Website`, the new session does not recognise the command.

If I run a session of **Windows Powershell**, I do not have to import the module, the command is already there.

Anyone able to explain what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference = 'All'` in your [profile script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles)

Comment: It should autoload.  Is the module not in the module path `$env:PSModulePath -split ';'`?  You could always import it in your `$profile`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. Thanks for that advice. I just tried that but the import did not persist across sessions.

Comment: @js2010
`$env:PSModulePath -split ';'` produces the following <br/>
`C:\Users\<<myusername>>\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules
c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\PowerShell\<br>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adaptiva\AdaptivaClient\data\PSModules`

Comment: @js2010.... this is a continuation of the above as I ran out of allowed text...

Oddly it is a combination of Windows Powershell and Powershell paths, some of which don't exist and one of which is not even a path, so I am assuming it's a shortcut powersehll can read.

The directory `WebAdministration` exists in the 7th of these (`C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`) which is a `Windows Powershell` directory as opposed to `Powershell`.

Should `Powershell` be able to pick it up?

Comment: @js2010 apologies for the formatting. Comments appear to be very limiting for that.

Comment: @kevins1966 Just to be clear: _module imports are **not supposed to persist** across sessions_.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. I see. If that is the case, what is the difference between Powershell and Windows Powershell because for the latter I do not ned to run `import-Module WebAdministration` for it to recognise 'get-command Get-Website`

Answer (score 2):

[You are not the only person having this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420700/specific-powershell-module-not-autoloading). Unfortunately, I can't speak to whether any of the solutions there work, as neither the asker or anyone else has confirmed them.

> **Note:** I had originally suspected this might be a problem with automatic importing through the `WindowsCompatibility` module, but it appears that [it does not interfere with auto-importing of modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility?view=powershell-7.2#using-the-compatibility-feature). In addition, as of PowerShell 7 the `WindowsCompatibility` module features are [baked into PowerShell itself](https://github.com/PowerShell/WindowsCompatibility#powershell-7).

For whatever reason, `WebAdministration` may not be able to be [automatically imported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-7.2#module-auto-loading) in **PowerShell Core**. There are a few reasons for this but they are mostly on the module side, and you can't change the behavior without modifying the module.

You can try setting `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference = 'All'` in your current PowerShell session, but generally that doesn't need to be changed from the default value of `ModuleQualified`. More information on `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psmoduleautoloadingpreference).

If that doesn't work, you'll have to manually import the module in every session.

---

Fortunately, manually importing modules isn't required for the vast majority of them. For the ones which can't be automatically imported, you must use `Import-Module MODULENAME` in each new session. You can simplify this by adding the `Import-Module` cmdlet to one of the following profile locations:

```
$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
$profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
$profile.AllUsersAllHosts
```

For scripts, `Import-Module` should generally be done inside the script to prevent needing profiles in scenarios where profile loading is desired to be disabled such as when **PowerShell** is invoked in the following way: `powershell.exe -NoProfile ....`

In your case, it would like like so:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

Here is some additional information about the [`$profile` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2#the-profile-variable).